# Unable to get repr for error in filtering records by foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, models

I am currently having error on the following query.

```
projects.objects.all()
```

Here is my code:

### Models.py

```
class ProjectManager(models.Manager):
"""A re-usable Manager to access a custom QuerySet"""

def __getattr__(self, attr, *args):
    try:
        return getattr(self.__class__, attr, *args)
    except AttributeError:
        return getattr(self.get_query_set(), attr, *args)

def get_query_set(self):
    return self.model.QuerySet(self.model)


class Project(models.Model):
objects = ProjectManager()

class QuerySet(QuerySet):
    def add_priority(self):
        return self.extra(select={"priority": "COALESCE(bm_rank, sales_rank, id)"}, order_by=["priority"])
        # return self.filter(*args, **kwargs)

    def add_size(self):
        return self.extra(select={"size": "order_size_price*order_size_weight"})
```

### Views.py

```
new_requests = projects.objects.all()
```

i am not sure why this error is coming, please help

Comment: Please provide a full stacktrace (`--traceback`)

Comment: Please also describe your code, is it view, model or what?